# Pandas df.isna().sum() not showing all column names

Tags: python, pandas

I have simple code in databricks:

```
import pandas as pd

data_frame = pd.read_csv('/dbfs/some_very_large_file.csv')
data_frame.isna().sum()

Out[41]:
A    0
B    0
C    0
D    0
E    0
     ..
T     0
V     0
X     0
Z     0
Y     0
Length: 287, dtype: int64
```

How can i see all column (A to Y) names along with is N/A values? Tried setting pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 287) and pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 287) but this doesn't seem to work here. Also isna() and sum() methods do not have any arguments that would allow me to manipulate output as far as i can say.

Comment: put some example data directly in code instead of `read_csv`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default settings for pandas display options are set  to 10 rows maximum. If the df to be displayed exceeds this number, it will be centrally truncated. To view the entire frame, you need to change the display options.

To display all rows of df:

```
pd.set_option('display.max_rows',None)
```

Ex:

```
>>> df
     A   B   C
0    4   8   8
1   13  17  13
2   19  13   2
3    9   9  16
4   14  19  19
..  ..  ..  ..
7    7   2   2
8    5   7   2
9   18  12  17
10  10   5  11
11   5   3  18

[12 rows x 3 columns]
>>> pd.set_option('display.max_rows',None)
>>> df
     A   B   C
0    4   8   8
1   13  17  13
2   19  13   2
3    9   9  16
4   14  19  19
5    3  17  12
6    9  13  17
7    7   2   2
8    5   7   2
9   18  12  17
10  10   5  11
11   5   3  18
```

Documentation:
[pandas.set_option](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.set_option.html)

Comment: This worked. pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 287) also works and i had it in my workbook, but i think somehow this got reversed to default value later. When i either put pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 287) or pd.set_option('display.max_rows',None) in the cell with data_frame.isna().sum() it works as expected.

Comment: It will revert to the default behavior of central truncation every time the pandas library is imported, as the 'set_option' does not change any environment variables. If you want to display the entire df every time you run the program, place the 'set_option' command at the top of the script. However, that is not recommended as printing a large dataframe will take up lots of resources. Instead, try and use a variable / dataframe viewer in your IDE. VS Code and PyCharm both have great variable explorers that allow you to glance at the dataframe without having to print to display.